# How to associate dynamically added input fields to parent element/id?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I design a user database system using bootstrap and jquery. The problem is, whenever a button is press, it will append an additional field for user to key in.

let's say the the array name for the first array of the field is `ref_title[0]`
after the append button is press, another text field will appear with the same attribute but the array value will be `ref_title[1]`.

however on the code itself, it will only show `ref_title[]`. This is ok, since any new field will keep adding on to the array `ref_title[]`. Am i right?

next when save changes button is clicked, i will direct the data to js using `onclick="newdata('<?php echo $row['drug_id']; ?>')"`

`'drug_id'` is a unique number, for example 1, 2 or 3.

when i inspect the input field for the first box is

```
<input class="form-control" id="ref_title3" name="ref_title[]" placeholder="Reference Title" type="text">
```

however on the second box(after the append button is press and additional box appeared)

```
<input class="form-control" id="ref_title" name="ref_title[]" placeholder="Reference Title" type="text">
```

Take a look at the `id="ref_title"`. The value 3 is not echo out.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ref_title<?php echo $row['drug_id'];?>" name="ref_title[]" placeholder="Reference Title">
<button type="button" onclick="newdata('<?php echo $row['drug_id']; ?>')" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="ref_title<?php echo $row['drug_id'];?>" name="ref_title[]" placeholder="Reference Title"/></div>"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box         
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

**Onlick**

```
function newdata(str){
var ref = $('#ref_title'+str).val(); // !!Only can read the first array 

var datas="&ref="+ref;

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "update.php",
   data: datas
}).done(function( data ) {
  $('#info').html(data);
  viewdata();
});
};
```

Comment: how do i read the array part? var ref = $('#ref_title'+str).val();?

Comment: Under "PHP" you have a text that might be part of an html input element, but is not php. Please elaborate.

Comment: ok its html sry about that

Comment: If you add a submit button to allow the form to be submitted, the entries will be available in PHP as an array `$_POST['ref_title']`.

Comment: ok the button will be
<button type="button" onclick="newdata('<?php echo $row['drug_id']; ?>')" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>

will be entering js

 var ref = $('#ref_title'+str).val();

Comment: @john I think you need to make it a bit clearer what you're asking. Also how did a new member get the username `john`?

Comment: Minor comment: `$(add_button).click(...` could just be `add_button.click(...` since it's already a jQuery object (and same with `$(wrapper)`).

Comment: ok let me edit a bit

Comment: ok should be it. Thanks a lot

Comment: "Take a look at the id="ref_title". The value 3 is not echo out. " a) you wouldn't want that, because there would be two elements having the same id and the value of that attribute is supposed to be unique throughout the document . b) Looks like `<?php echo $row['drug_id'];?>` didn't output anything when the document was served. Do you run your php script with [error_reporting](http://docs.php.net/errorfunc.configuration#ini.error-reporting)=E_ALL and (if it is purely a development server) [display_errors](http://docs.php.net/errorfunc.configuration#ini.display-errors)=1 ?

Comment: @VolkerK i see your point. If not, which way is better to pass to js?

Comment: I don't know since I do not understand what you're exaclty trying to achieve.

Comment: alright, i wan to read all the input value from `ref_title[]` array then put it to js. Since Js only refer to the input "id=ref_title" for the value.

Comment: That's "how you want to achieve something", not "what you want to achieve" ;-)

Comment: basically when user wan to key in another value in the text input. The user can add more field by clicking the add more function. For example, a medical drug have 3 references. so when user key in the first reference, he will click the add button to display the second reference field. and follow by the third. These references title will be stored in an array which is called `ref_title[]`. so right now i wan to pass this value into js. which seems to be not working.

Comment: "need help in array in js" Fix your title please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but a suggestion on what you *could* do.

Prerequisite: test.php

```
<pre><?php var_export($_POST); ?></pre>
```

When you give input controls a name containing `[...]` php will treat the data as if it were arrays. E.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="test.php">

            <input type="hidden" name="foo[a]" value="a" />
            <input type="hidden" name="foo[b]" value="b" />
            <input type="hidden" name="foo[bar][]" value="bar1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="foo[bar][]" value="bar2" />
            <input type="hidden" name="foo[bar][]" value="bar3" />
            <div>
                <input type="submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

the ouput of test.php will be

```
<pre>array (
  'foo' => 
  array (
    'a' => 'a',
    'b' => 'b',
    'bar' => 
    array (
      0 => 'bar1',
      1 => 'bar2',
      2 => 'bar3',
    ),
  ),
)</pre>
```

i.e. the names

```
name="foo[a]"
name="foo[b]"
name="foo[bar][]"
name="foo[bar][]"
name="foo[bar][]"
```

caused php to build the _POST array like

```
$_POST = array();
$_POST['foo']['a'] = 'a';
$_POST['foo']['b'] = 'b';
// $_POST['foo'][bar] = array()
$_POST['foo']['bar'][] = 'bar1';
$_POST['foo']['bar'][] = 'bar2';
$_POST['foo']['bar'][] = 'bar3';
```

Now I suggest that you build the names for the input controls like this:

```
[drugs][145][add][]
```

telling hte php script that it is supposed to work on drug items, which one (145), that it should add something plus the [] so you can add an (virtually) arbitrary amount of items.
So a POST body like

```
drugs[145][add][]=drug145.1&drugs[145][add][]=drug145.2&drugs[22][add][]=drug22.1
```

(yeah, yeah, the encoding is off....)

would lead to

```
_POST==$_POST = array(
    'drugs' = >array(
        '145' => array(
            'add' => array(
                'drug145.1',
                'drug145.2'
            ),
        '22' => array(
            'add' => 'drug22.1'
        )
    )
);
```

telling your php script to add/append the two descriptions `drug145.1` and `drug145.2` to the item 145 and `drug22.1` to the item 22.

And here's an example how you *can* do this with html/javascript/jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            .adddrugdesc {
                margin-left: 1em;
                cursor: pointer;
                background-color: Cornsilk;
                border: 1px solid silver;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method="post" action="test.php">
            <div class="druglist">      
                <!-- note the drugid as an data-* attribute, see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes
                Your php script is supposed to output this id when serving the html document
                -->
                <fieldset><legend data-drugid="3">Drug A</legend></fieldset>
                <fieldset><legend data-drugid="7">Drug B</legend></fieldset>
                <fieldset><legend data-drugid="145">Drug C</legend></fieldset>
                <fieldset><legend data-drugid="22">Drug D</legend></fieldset>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var dl = $(".druglist");
                // add some kind of edit/add button to each fieldset/legend 
                dl.find("fieldset legend").each(function(x) {
                    $(this).append('<span class="adddrugdesc">add description</span>');
                });

                // add an event handler for all edit/add buttons
                dl.on('click', '.adddrugdesc', function(e) {
                    var me = $(this); // this will be the span element the usr clicked on
                    var legend = me.parent('legend'); // this will be the legend element in which the span is located
                    var fset = legend.parent('fieldset'); // same as with legend

                    var drugid = legend.data()['drugid']; // access the data-* attribute of the element via data() and pick the element "drugid"

                    var newinput = $('<input type="text" />');
                    newinput.attr("name", "drugs["+drugid+"][add][]");
                    fset.append(newinput);
                });

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

(It's a bit verbose to keep it "understandable". And ...it's only an example. Some things might be a bit prettier, more robust et al)